# Vertical align form element in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

It's the very first time I'm using bootstrap 4 and I thought it's supposed to be easy to vertical align elements as I read everywhere flex is the easiest thing to vertical align elements.

**The problem:**
I'm struggling with vertical aligning my form element inside of my navigation bar. Once I assign a different font-size for the text input element it becomes smaller and is not vertically aligned anymore:[image]

**My HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md py-3 navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TMS</a><button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bd-main-nav" aria-controls="bd-main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button></div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bd-main-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav right-spacer">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/features">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/features">Demo</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

                <form class="navbar-form" role="search"><input class="header-search-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" name="q"></form>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login/">Sign in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**The custom CSS:**

```
.navbar-dark .header-search-input {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-size: .7rem;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/qo33wf3d/ (Resize the output window otherwise it will show the empty responsive version)

Comment: it seems working on ur jsfiddle ?? the collapesed navbar are vertically aligned !

Comment: It's about the vertical alignment of the text input: http://i.imgur.com/lKx0nC2.png

Comment: @kentor check the link https://jsfiddle.net/qo33wf3d/1/

Comment: I am not looking for a static solution if it's avoidable @chiragsolanki

Comment: if can  you keep font bigger than it should same size?

Comment: Please check it updated links... what I suggest 
https://jsfiddle.net/qo33wf3d/3/  here you can change font-size and alignment is same

Comment: @kentor Use .form-control{  line-height: 2; }

Comment: @Nimish that doesn't align it perfectly either.

Comment: @kentor At my end it is perfectly aligned. Tried in same fiddle you shared. Try 1.75 value for line height.

Comment: @Nimish I am not looking for try'n'error solutions, I am looking for a proper way of vertical aligning my elements. Otherwise I would have used margin-top as suggested already.

Comment: @kentor I have noticed that the the bootstrap css is applying font-size: 1rem; and you have modified it to font-size: 0.7rem; and as you modified it you have to align the form applying your css. There is no proper way to align the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `my-auto` class on the form...

```
       <form class="navbar-form my-auto" role="search">
            <input class="header-search-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" name="q">
       </form>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Zo1Ci90MbH

Comment: Finally, day saver <3. By the way codeply loaded endlessly for me but the snippet was enough :).